# Is there a way to force fail the transaction in testnet network

Tags: transactions, testnet

I would like to test my application with all the edge cases. Could you please tell me is there a way to force fail the transaction in the testnet blockchain so I can test if my application handles that case correctly.

Thank you for the answers in advance.

Comment: Hi Goran, Could you please be more specific what type of failure you mean? If you mean "not included in a block", you could just not publish it to the network.

Comment: The type of failure i mean is that when it is published but orphaned (or any other failure)

Comment: So, a doublespend?

Answer (score -1):

You can set fees to very low (for example 1500 for a small 1 input 1 output transaction), not zero though. That will (most likely) get your transaction to be not mined in a few days and dropped.

Comment: Does that work on testnet?

Comment: I would avoid testnet if possible. It's not really behaving like a real one.